# How to create a cumulative power BI Funnel

Tags: powerbi, power-platform

[image: Funnel]

Hi, let’s say I currently have an excel table with a column titled ‘Letter’ and the rows in that column either appear as A, B, C, D, E or F. I want to create a funnel for the count of each letter but I want it to displays each bar as the total minus the one before it. Basically, the first bar would be A+B+C+D+E+F, the second would be B+C+D+E+F, the third C+D+E+F and so on.

Could someone please help me create a measure to do this? I’m really new to power BI and don’t know how I’d do this.

Here is a snippet of the data. Each letter corresponds to a stage in a sales pipeline. To have reached any stage in the funnel, it will have first have to been at the stage before, hence why I want them to all be added up.

[image]

This is how I currently plug this data into the funnel

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need a numeric version of your `Pipeline stage`. You can have this in a separate table similar to:

Table name: `Dim Pipeline stage`

| Stage | Stage order |
| --- | --- |
| Proposal | 1 |
| Meeting / Presentation / Demo | 2 |
| Work won / Solution sold | 3 |
| Lost | 9 |

Then add a relationship to your Pipeline table. Select the `Stage` column and then do a `Sort by column` on `Stage order`.

You would use `'Dim Pipeline stage'[Stage]` for your chart `Category`. Then create a Measure similar to:

```
Pipeline stage cumulative count = 
  var thisStage = MIN('Dim Pipeline stage'[Stage order])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('YourPipelineTable'),
      REMOVEFILTERS('Dim Pipeline stage'),
      'Dim Pipeline stage'[Stage order] >= thisStage
    )
```

And add this measure to your chart `Values`.

For other visuals, you can use the same measure as and where needed. See image below, where "Meeting..." is selected in the funnel, and how the other visuals continue to show the proceeding stages.

[image]

Comment: Hi, so my table doesn't actually have a count column. Are you suggesting to first create this new table, and then use this in the funnel? Apologies if I misunderstood, but is that formula you provided creating the new column? My data is actually a sales pipeline, each letter is a stage in that. E.g. A is Lead, B is demo and so on. I updated the original post with what my data looks like, and the way I currently create the visual.

Comment: The formula I gave is for a Measure, and you would use that in the `Values` of the visual. What you will need is a numeric version of your `Pipeline stage`. See the updated answer above for more on that. No, you don't need a count column.

Comment: Thank you. Why is the stage order for lost = 9?

Comment: In case you want to add more stages in between and to make it easier to remember for when you want to filter it out. Please help mark the answer as Accepted (the check mark under the voting buttons) for the benefit of all.

Comment: Okay thanks, I actually did it a different way in the end, however it didn't let me filter on other visuals by clicking, so once I test out your way I will mark as accepted if it works.

Comment: Hopefully the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77942589/if-you-create-a-visual-with-custom-measures-does-clicking-on-this-visual-still) explains why it is best to have dimensions on your visual for cross-filtering/cross-highlighting.

Comment: Hi, this works, but still gives me the same issue as one of my other approaches. The visual displays correctly, as each section of the chart displays that stage plus the following stages. E.g Meeting displays as meeting + Proposal + work won etc. However, when I click on this section of the chart, it only filters the rest of the visuals by the occurrences of Meeting in the larger table, rather than meeting + proposal + work won. So only filters based on the ones that didn't make it past that stage, but that isn't what the visual displays. e.g. meeting stage displays as 74, but filters by 21.

Comment: Use the same measure in the other visuals and should work the same.

Comment: The other visuals are not tracking sales pipeline stages though. They are based on the rest of the table, which I may not have made clear - apologies. They are not visuals of the same data, but they are visuals based on data from the same table. The table has multiple columns, pipeline stage is just one of those. Other columns for example are Company sector, product type etc. I want it to filer these visuals when clicking on the pipeline visual.

Comment: I have made a minor tweak to the measure (replaced `ALLSELECTED` with `REMOVEFILTERS('Dim Pipeline stage')`). Also provided a snip of it interacting with other visuals. The other visuals do not need anything to do with the stage.

Comment: Did the updated answer work out for you?