# If you create a visual with custom measures, does clicking on this visual still filter related visuals?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-platform

I created a new visual with some custom measures.

Now, when I click on any other visual, it still filters the rest of the visuals same as before (including the new visual). But clicking on the new visual itself doesn't filter the others.

Essentially, the new visual (with custom measures) can be filtered by all other visuals, but not vice versa. What is creating this one way flow?
Is this always going to be the case when you use custom measures?

The new visual is a funnel using pipeline stages from a sales pipeline. The pipeline stage is one column in a wider table of sales data which I have used for other visuals.

I created a separate measure for each one of the bars (the pipeline stage) in the funnel visual. For example:

`CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Combined Leads'),FILTER('Combined Leads','Combined Leads'[Pipeline stage] <> "Lead Qualification" &&'Combined Leads'[Pipeline stage] <> "Meeting / Presentation"`

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the interaction between visuals, by default it will apply cross-highlight or cross-filter between the chosen visual and all the others in the page.

[Visual Interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop)

Your measures can ignore these filters using DAX, by adding/removing filters you can ignore or overwrite the filter context imposed by the interaction from other visuals.

Check the query being generated by the visual with Performance Analyzer and you should see some TREATAS variables being issued on the query, those are the filters.

Answer (score 1):

Your visual with multiple measures is "dimension-less" and so when selecting one of those measures, it will have no dimension to cross-filter/cross-highlight other visuals.

If you take the approach suggested in the answer to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938332/how-to-create-a-cumulative-power-bi-funnel/), it has a dimension and one measure on the visual, so when you select a dimension, that dimension is applied as filter context to the other visuals.